# ZZ plant yellowing question

Tags: watering, zzplant

I'm starting to see yellowing of some of the leaves and I've seen conflicting advice online. Here's the full story:

- I got it two weeks ago and put it on a saucer with water the moment I got home, it was after I took it out, after about 20 minutes, that I saw on the label that the store actually puts the date of the last watering and it had been two days before.
- The place where I keep it does get indirect light, but it's on the darker side of the spectrum so every day I've been putting it next to a window, around 9:00 and get it back to "its spot" around 14:00 just as the sun begins to hit it directly.
- The earth does feel quite dry, but I keep reading that overwatering is very bad for this plant and that they should be watered "as often as you pay the rent", so I am unsure if I should water it again.
- Next week I'll be out for two weeks, so I was thinking of bottom watering again on Friday before I leave. So it would be three weeks since its last bottom watering.

Today I saw that one of the leaves is fully yellow and the rest of the leaves seem to be getting lighter in color.

I'm really unsure of what to do. Should I bottom water it now or should I wait just before I leave for two weeks? If I water it now, will it be suffering by the time I get back (I know nobody is a fortune teller, but I'm asking for an educated guess based on your experience)? Should I keep it in its less illuminated corner?

Any recommendation is well appreciated. Thank you.
[image]

Comment: Water once a month per the card. Top, bottom, doesn't matter.

Comment: Losing a few leaves to yellowing is part of the transition from ideal greenhouse life to home life.

Answer (score 0):

Note that bottom watering only works if your dish is tall enough so that the water from the dish can soak into the pot.

And you top it up, wait for the pot to soak it up and top it up again.